# Copy specific text file to specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

I´m working on .txt file, and I would like to copy certain specific data to my Excel worksheet. 
I´m new in programming with VBA.

The files have inside:

```
 METAR LPAZ 012300Z 27003KT 9999 FEW020 13/09 Q1008= 
 METAR LPAZ 012200Z 24008KT 7000 FEW025 14/09 Q1009= 
 METAR LPAZ 012100Z 26005KT 9999 FEW026 14/09 Q1008=
```

but I just want to put on the worksheet specific info, such as:

21 260 05 9999 026 (21 of 012100, 260 of 26005KT, 05 of 26005KT, 026 of FEW026)
22 240 08 7000 025
23 270 03 9999 020

Answer (score 0):

Import your text file (Data > Get External Data - From Text) and with Fixed width set parsing as below:

[image: SO15952238 example]

then sort AZ.

If you want the 5 values per row (assuming starting in `A1`) in the same cell with space separation use `=A1&" "&B1&" "&C1&" "&D1&" "&E1` (leave out all the `&" "` if not to be space separated).

Note that the import format must be Text for those elements that start `0`.